# Xamarin Forms Navigation page inside shell

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

### UPDATE

I used @Deczaloth his awnser, but I still end up with a black content page.
Here is my current xaml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<transition:TransitionShellPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       xmlns:transition="clr-namespace:Memento.PageTransitionControls"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Memento"
       Title="ShellTest"
       x:Class="Memento.AppShell"
       BackgroundColor="#212121">

    <Shell.FlyoutHeader>
        <local:SideMenuHeader />
    </Shell.FlyoutHeader>

    <Shell.TitleView>
        <Image Source="Title_Dark.png" HeightRequest="30" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </Shell.TitleView>

    <Shell.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="30, 15, 0, 15">
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" HeightRequest="35" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="White" FontSize="Large" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.ItemTemplate>

    <FlyoutItem Title="SideNav"
                Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"
                FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent Title="Home" Icon="Home_Dark.png" IsTabStop="true" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}"/>
        <ShellContent Title="Search" Icon="Search_Dark.png" IsTabStop="true" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Messages" Icon="Chats_Dark.png" IsTabStop="true" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Favorites" Icon="Favorites_Dark.png" IsTabStop="true" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Settings" Icon="Settings_Dark.png" IsTabStop="true" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>

</transition:TransitionShellPage>
```

And here is the C# behind the code:

```
public partial class AppShell : TransitionShellPage
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And finally, the screenshot of my current app result:
[image]
Now what am I doing wrong, because I think I followed his awnser!

Any suggestions!?

Comment: Can you please provide us a  [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  ? What's the `Controls.TransitionNavigationPage` here, I can't reproduce the problem so far.

Comment: I added the `Controls.TransitionNavigationPage` code to the question. I think that should be enough. In the code is a variable called `TransitionType`. That is an enum with transitions like Fade and Flip, but I don't think that that is relevant code!

Comment: According to your code you post, I can't reproduce your problem so far, is it convenient for you to post a basic demo or more complete code  so that we can help you better? I am confused with the code `MainShell.Items[0].Items[0].Items[0].ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(HomePage)); ` .

Comment: That code is how I set the first content page that would be loaded in the shell. Now I want to load HomePage, but as a TransitionNavigationPage (a custom NavigationPage). That is where the code is for. Right now, the page gets loaded as default format!

Comment: I actually just want a custom navigation page inside a shell!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your problem is one of concept, as i see it. You are trying to combine two different ***Navigation*** paradigms! The whole idea of `Shell` is to provide a different **Navigation** paradigm as was available with `NavigationPage`, so my advice would be: Rethink your approach.

---

### Possible alternative:

Since as i see, the only purpose of using your custom `NavigationPage` is to define the `BindableProperty` `TransitionType`, i would suggest that you create in a similar way a custom `Shell` as follows:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ShellTest
{

    public class TransitionShellPage : Shell
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty TransitionTypeProperty =
                BindableProperty.Create("TransitionType", typeof(TransitionType), typeof(TransitionNavigationPage), TransitionType.SlideFromLeft);

        public TransitionType TransitionType
        {
            get { return (TransitionType)GetValue(TransitionTypeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TransitionTypeProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can simply make your traditional AppShell inherit from that custom Shell class as follows:

### Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<this:TransitionShellPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       xmlns:this="clr-namespace:ShellTest"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ShellTest.Views"
       Title="ShellTest"
       x:Class="ShellTest.AppShell">

    <TabBar>
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent>
                 <!-- This launches your HomePage -->
                <local:HomePage />
            </ShellContent>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>

</this:TransitionShellPage>
```

### C#:

```
public partial class AppShell : TransitionShellPage
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then you just call this from App.xaml.cs like:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new AppShell();
}
```

Read more on Shell in the [MSDN docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/), or other post on the topic like this from [Eduardo Rosas](https://lalorosas.com/blog/shell).

Comment: Okay, I really appreciate your help, but still a few questions: how or what do I need to call to show the HomePage. Now I call a default Shell page... Do I need to call the class? And if so, then you TrnasitionShellPage has xaml?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk, i added some more details in my answer. Nevertheless, i would strongly recommend you dive into the Shell docu (a good read XD)

Comment: Still not the wanted result. Check my question, because I updated it with my new code combined with yours!

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk, I see your update. I think you are having an issue primarily with your SideMenuHeader: remove the whole declaration of FlyoutHeader and see if that helps: (acctually, when you start the application the first thing you should see is the HomePage! and not the "Master" as seems to be your case)

Comment: I removed the declaration but still black screen.... Also my upper bar is not with list items!?

Comment: Well, to me it looks like something is going wrong with your design. To find out exactly what i would suggest you start with the simplest, as in the sample code i shared, and from there you start to elaborate your design.

Comment: It already gives a black screen when I only set the shell content.... What could be wrong with the HomePage, because I tried it with every page, but they all give a black screen!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205260/discussion-between-a-vreeswijk-and-deczaloth).